# unit test framework + code coverage tool for C++

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks, code-coverage

We should select tool for our C++ code.
Is there a same tool or the tools of the same company for unit test framework
and code coverage tests?
Our aim if the both tool can work compatibly.
Sorry for my english
Thank you very much

Comment: These questions provide part of the answers: [Free Testing / Code Coverage systems for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161832/), [Is there any free C++ code coverage tool which is useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84109/). If you are looking for commercial tool, please specify (i) the operating system, (ii) compiler / IDE, (iii) budget for the test tools.

Comment: You may want to check this question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458186/open-source-c-code-coverage-tool-with-gui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used both CxxTest and GoogleTest and both do the job, with a main difference that the former is using pre-build script to generate the test driver code and the later uses static registration of tests which the driver later uses.

For coverage under Windows Bullseye Cover is a great product.

Answer (score 2):

For code coverage you can use the [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) tool and as Unit test Framework you can take a look at the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/test/doc/html/index.html)